# How can I have a public searchable GitHub account?

Tags: google-search, github

My GitHub account is public: `https://github.com/`*`USER`*. I can see my name even if not connected (active *Sign up*, *Sign in* buttons).

However, I cannot find my projects when searching after it (Google, Bing) even if I add `github` or even if I use my username on the site or even directly on GitHub. What setting should I change?

Comment: Not private: "Make this repository private / Please upgrade your plan to make this repository private." But it has an interesting feature checked: "Restrict editing to collaborators only / Public wikis will still be readable by everyone."

Comment: It just solved ... by itself, now it is the fifth item in the search list ... even if I did nothing for one year. Then I must hurry!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to GitHub's [robots.txt](https://github.com/robots.txt),  the only section Google is allowed to index is the master branch of a project, so your account will only be indexed if you have one of those in your project (and it isn't private).

If you have a master branch then it could just be that Google hasn't gotten to you yet. You can try [submitting your URL](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) which might speed things up.

Comment: It is the master branch, it's not private since I can see it using the URL in another browser, not connected (the buttons "Sign up", "Sign in" look very active). Google didn't find me in ... 8 months?  It was very fast with Linkedin, facebook, etc. I'll try to submit my URL.

Comment: Solved without submitting, by divine intervention?, but I guess the answer is straight accurate.

Comment: Liviu - I am having the same problem, that my very public github repo is not visible. Its been almost 2 weeks since I checked in the repo. How did your git project start appearing in google search finally ?

Comment: @BinitaBharati It took even longer for myself, but I was not in a hurry. Have you tried the advice in the answer, that's it to submit the URL yourself to Google?